# BrowserRouter keyLength property is not working properly

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Documentation says about **keyLength**

> The length of location.key. Defaults to 6.

Then why if I give **keyLength** property 15 it show me only 11 symbols?

```
<BrowserRouter keyLength={15}>
   <App />
</BrowserRouter>
```

---

```
<Route
    exact
    path="/"
    render={({ location }) => (
      <div> In User, Location Key: {location.key} </div>
    )}
  />
```

Link to [**Codesandbox**](https://codesandbox.io/s/a-simple-react-router-v4tutorial-u0ql8?file=/components/Main.js:496-651)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see it is documented anywhere, but from the source code it looks like 11 is the maximum length.

The `BrowserRouter` component uses the following function from the `history` package to generate a key:

```
function createKey() {
  return Math.random()
    .toString(36)
    .substr(2, keyLength);
}
```

see: https://github.com/ReactTraining/history/blob/v4/modules/createBrowserHistory.js#L74

It generates random number, converts it to string and then strips 2 symbols at the beginning. With this approach the maximum length of a key is 11.